# Pepper : Code doesn't work fine after naoqi upgrade

Tags: python, pepper

I have the python code of one of my colleague (who left my company). Pepper asks what do you  you want, you answer that you want a cocktail, Pepper ask you which cocktailm do you want, you give it a cocktail name, Pepper ask you if you have all the ingredients (only two ingredients) and give you the recipe.
The application worked fine before my colleague left. The naoqi version was the 2.1 version.
I upgrade naoqi on Pepper two weeks ago, and, when i test the code (with no modification), I have the following message  :

> *RuntimeError:    ALSpeechRecognition::setVocabulary 
>         NuanceContext::addContext 
>  A grammar named
>   "modifiable_grammar_wordspotting" already exists.*

Here's the code of my function :

```
   def onInput_onStart(self, enableWordSpotting):
        from threading import Lock
        self.mutex.acquire()
        if(self.bIsRunning):
            self.mutex.release()
            return
        self.bIsRunning = True
        try:
            if self.asr:
                self.asr.pause(True)#need to pause the ASR system while configuring it
                self.asr.setVisualExpression(True)
                self.asr.pushContexts()
            self.hasPushed = True
            if self.asr:
                self.asr.setLanguage(language)
                self.asr.setVocabulary(self.listPhrToReco, enableWordSpotting)

            self.memory.subscribeToEvent("WordRecognized", self.getName(), "onWordRecognized")
            self.hasSubscribed = True
            self.asr.pause(False)#
            self.phrReco = "" #additional layer to recover the last recognized sentence (ow. it is only accessible from callback:on )
        except RuntimeError, e:
            self.mutex.release()
            self.onUnload()
            raise e
        self.mutex.release()
```

Hers's the specific line who generated teh error:

```
self.asr.setVocabulary(self.listPhrToReco, enableWordSpotting)
```

Noticed that in the first execution of the speech recognition, I haven't the error, Pepper reconize the first word (cocktail), ask me what I want, it reconize the name of the cocktail, it ask me if I had the first ingredient, I say yes, and when it ask me for the second ingredient, the error occurs. After, even I relaunch the scripts, I have the error before the first word recognition. 
Has anyone got an idea of the origin of the problem please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to setVocabukary twice without having the ASR stopped. Try to add a removeAllContext to your code at the end?

Comment: Thank you JLS. I had a popcontext which didn't work, and I had commented it. So, the last context wasn't remove. With the remove allcontext, the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

set `asr.pause(False)` before unsubscribing